# How to create a Google App Script to save RSS's content daily

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

My goal is to create an App Script on Google Spreadsheet to:

1. Access my sheet "Sheet1"
2. Find the last row of column A2
3. Insert the formula
   =IMPORTFEED("https://trends.google.com/trends/trendingsearches/daily/rss?geo=BR")
4. Add the current date to column A1 when there's a content on the
   column A2
5. Paste special all the Spreadsheet's content since it's a daily RSS (and get updated)
6. Run the script daily at 10pm

```
function myFunction() {

  const ss1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+3", "dd/MM/yyyy")
  var lastRowInd = ss1.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getLastRow() + 1;

  var rss = getRange(1,1,lastRowInd).setFormula(`=IMPORTFEED("https://trends.google.com/trends/trendingsearches/daily/rss?geo=BR")`);

  ss1.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getRange(1,1,lastRowInd).setValue(rss);

}
```

Comment: Can you explain what issues you're having with your code? You've explained what you want to happen, but what is actually happening? Are you seeing any errors?

Comment: Try XMLService.

Answer (score 1):

#### Modification points:

- In your showing script, at `var rss = getRange(1,1,lastRowInd).setFormula(`=IMPORTFEED("https://trends.google.com/trends/trendingsearches/daily/rss?geo=BR")`);`, `getRange` is not declared. By this, an error occurs.
- I thought that `ss1.getSheetByName('Sheet1')` can be used only one time.
- About `getRange(1,1,lastRowInd)`, in this case, the cells "A1:A(lastRow)" are used. The arguments of `getRange` is [getRange(row, column, numRows)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows) and [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns).

When these points and your showing flow are reflected in a sample script, how about the following sample script?

#### Modified script:

```js
function setTrigger() {
  const triggerFunction = "myFunction";
  const t = ScriptApp.getProjectTriggers().find(t => t.getHandlerFunction() == triggerFunction);
  if (t) {
    ScriptApp.deleteTrigger(t);
  }
  const triggerTime = new Date();
  if (triggerTime.getHours() >= 22) {
    triggerTime.setDate(triggerTime.getDate() + 1);
  }
  triggerTime.setHours(22, 0, 0, 0);
  ScriptApp.newTrigger(triggerFunction).timeBased().at(triggerTime).create();
}

function myFunction() {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1";
  const date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT+3", "dd/MM/yyyy");

  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheetName);
  const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow() + 1;
  const range = sheet.getRange(lastRow, 2)
  range.setFormula(`=IMPORTFEED("https://trends.google.com/trends/trendingsearches/daily/rss?geo=BR")`);
  SpreadsheetApp.flush();
  const src = range.offset(0, 0, sheet.getLastRow() - lastRow + 1, sheet.getLastColumn() - 1);
  src.setValues(src.getValues());
  sheet.getRange(lastRow, 1).setValue(date);

  setTrigger();
}
```

- From `Run the script daily at 10pm`, when you want to run `myFunction` every day at 10 pm, please run `setTrigger()`. By this, the time-driven trigger is installed.
- When you test the script and install the next time-driven trigger, please run `myFunction()`.
- When `myFunction` is run, the formula is put into cell "B(lastRow + 1)" and the retrieved values are fixed as the values. And, the next trigger is set.
- If you want to keep the formula, please remove `const src = range.offset(0, 0, sheet.getLastRow() - lastRow + 1, sheet.getLastColumn() - 1); src.setValues(src.getValues());`.

#### References:

- [getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns) of Class sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getrangerow,-column,-numrows,-numcolumns).
- [newTrigger(functionName)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#newtriggerfunctionname)